# Finding P(X+Y>1) with the joint pdf

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I know this seems to be a very basic question, but I have been struggling with this.
If two random variables have joint density f(x, y) = K(3x + 4y) & 0 < x < 4, 0 < y < 3
I want to find P(X+Y>1). Which I approached as 1-P(X+Y<1). For me P(X+Y<1) always turns to be negative in my calculation. I used 0 < x < 1-y, 0 < y < 3.

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please show your work so that we can tell you what mistake you made.

Comment: Note that $x,y >0$ and $x+y <1$ forces $y$ to be less than $1$.

Comment: Yes, I have computed P(x+y < 1) and then P(x+y > 1) = 1- P(x+y < 1). I have found that K=1/144 and integrated the function with limits 0 < x < 1-y, 0 < y < 3. This gave me negative answer even in MATLAB.

Comment: As already pointed out you have to take $0<y<1$. You will not get a negative value if you do this.

Comment: How does this work? I don't clearly understand why we change the limits of y.

Comment: Choosing (say) $y=2$ will mean (due to wanting $x+y<1$) that $x<-1$ which is outside the support of your distribution.

Comment: I Add it would be nice if you'd add tex notation ( dollar brackets)

Comment: @Perceus If the sum of two *positive* reals is less than $1$, then *neither* may be greater than $1$.

Comment: Thank you. I am just learning. I will necessary research hereafter before asking questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If two random variables have joint density $f(x, y) = K(3x + 4y) \mathbf 1_{ 0 < x < 4, 0 < y < 3}$ I want to find $P(X+Y>1)$

You wish to integrate over $0<x<4,0<y<3$ *and* $0<x+y<1$.

This is $0<y<1, 0<x<1-y$.  Because if the sum of two positive reals is less than 1, then neither may be greater than 1.

$$\mathsf P(X+Y>1)=1-(1/144)\int_0^1\int_0^{1-y} (3x+4y)\,\mathrm dx\,\mathrm d y$$